# Idea on building a live, serverless multi-user local-network-shared database with SQLite

Tags: sqlite, concurrency

I need some input on a idea I had. If you're interested/experienced in SQLite and lowest-budget-high-end-solutions (Win only for now ;)) this is for you.
While fleshing out this question I have gotten pretty excited about this idea, so bear with me. 
**There's a TL;DR below**

I have developed a VB.NET (3.5) Desktop application with SQLite. The data is structured in an EAV-model, because I need that flexibility (the semantic structure of the data is stored separately in an XML File). The application actually performs very well above my expectations, even with a - for the scenario at hand - large database (about 120MB for the main file).

As expected performance is abysmal when the SQLite file(s) are on a network folder. It's bearable but I have higher goals. Expected scenarios (for now) are max. 10 users that need to access the database concurrently within a local windows network. 98% of the concurrence is required for heavy read-access, inserts and updates are sparse and small.

The software is used almost exclusively within environments with low budget and the technical infrastructure (support and hardware) even lower, so my goal is to avoid using a database server. I also do not want to implement my own SQLite "Server" a la SQLitening (i.e. tell one instance of the application to automagically "share" the database in the network) because i want the database to be able to reside on an independent network drive.

My first impulse after realizing the situation cannot be amended by optimizing queries, was a "lazy synchronization" approach which would be mostly painless to implement. The database is "wiki-esque" with (almost) only inserts, so there won't be any (much) conflict issues at all: whoever comes "last" wins, each field has a change history with timestamp and userid and can be rolled back individually. Entries are "marked as deleted" and can be discarded upon a "cleanup"-action.
Though it comes at the cost of never being "live" with the data other users change or enter during a session, and also the synching process might take a while, with the users potentially blocking each other at "rush-hour". We're talking maybe a couple of minutes worst-case, which wouldn't be a big deal but it wouldn't be cool, either.

**TL;DR:** How to implement a live, serverless, local-network-shared Database with SQLite for a end-user application that already performs very well on a local datafile within a scenario with

- **many** SELECTs
- **few** INSERTs
- **no** DELETEs and
- **hardly any** UPDATEs per user session.

Let's assume furthermore

- there is **always sufficient hard drive space** available
- due to archive mechanisms (and data privacy constraints) the database **never grows above 200MB**
- we can efficiently tell whether a file has been changed and by whom in the "shared directory" where the database files reside
- we can copy files sufficiently fast from the shared directory

Now what i had in mind was implementing differencing files for each session that will be locally cached for read access.

At the start of a client-session:

- check the big file and session-specific (see below) files in the shared directory for changes since the last session (CRC+logfile in the shared directory)
- copy the big (200MB) current database file **to a local path** before each session if changed or not cached
- also copy all session-specific files (see below) if changed or not cached
- all INSERTs during a session are written to a small, session-specific file **in the shared directory**

  - this could be limited to a suitable size like 2MB per file or something even smaller, then a new file is created
- read-access (SELECTs) is then performed sequentially

  - in the local copy of the main file
  - in the local copies of the session files
  - in all current (ie. new) session files in the shared cache
- on detection of a new session file, session files will by copied to the local cache again
- finally, the session files are periodically merged into the big file

  - this could be at the end of every session, but if I am not mistaken, it could be whenever.

This would

- eliminate all write concurrency
- eliminate read concurrency on the big file and all local session files
- reduce the needed concurrency to the reads on the small session files
- minimize the network usage to accessing the most current session files (2MB per concurrent user)
- preserve a live view of the current data state for every client

This sounds beyond awesome to me.

Questions:
Is there a name for this "protocol" that i am outlining so I can do further research?

Would you consider this is a viable approach with SQLite or is this a wild goose chase - am I overlooking obvious drawbacks?

If you're on board, what would be a good size for the session files (n * page_size?)?

Thank you for your input!

Christoph

Answer (score 0):

It seams to me that you're trying reinventing the wheel!

Your application overhead, such as copying big database file, will for sure overrun ultra tunned SQLite engine. And a lot privacy concerns should arise from this approach (maybe not in your case, but in a isolated server/client environment).

Also, your "custom RDBMS" will for sure break ACID compliance.

At last, your requirements seams to fit very well in [Situations Where SQLite Works Well](http://www.sqlite.org/whentouse.html).

Comment: Sorry can you elaborate on that? What privacy concerns? The application runs in an isolated environment. Every SQLite file is encrypted with a 4096Bit key. The employees need shared access.

Comment: And I was asking specifically asking for a name of "that wheel". The overhead is practically null. The files grow about 1MB per Session - that is the amount that needs to be copied. How does it break ACID? Doesn't every WIKI-like database do that? And as I wrote: SQLite works very well - with single user access. Multi-user access is abysmal. The application i am talking about is already in prductive use and the multi-user access needs tuning. I am sorry but i don't understand any of your points.

Comment: Have you tested using SQLite in multiuser environment yet? I would start from there. I'm convinced that with your requirements, SQLite will perform quite well.

Comment: You're saying "SQLite file is encrypted"? Whole database or table data? If it is whole database, you are running non standard SQLite engine, which can degrade engine performance.

Comment: I'm using System.Data.SQLite and the whole file is encrypted. I have not noticed any performance gain with unencrypted Databases. I have tested in mu-environment and as soon as the file is accessed by more than one user via windows-network, the performance drops significantly. But I am still refining some queries and parallel db-tasks that could be the reason for this.

Comment: I too was convinced that SQLite could handle this but I'm afraid I have optimized too much for single-user access and have reached a dead end for multi-user access, such that a lower-level solution is required. But I am not sure. Don't get me wrong: I don't WANT to implement the solution i sketched, i just cannot think of other ways to improve the network performance.

Comment: Ok, against fact there are no arguments! Anyway, I would think in migrating my database to Microsoft SQL Server, MySQL, MariaDB or other engine before starting to implement a custom solution. Good luck!